# Is there any method can set different labels with plot.gam?

Tags: r, plot, gam

I am trying to plot my gam result. I want to turn the labels of the plots into Chinese. But, the x label will be used  for all plots. How to creat different x-labels for different plots?
`fit <- gam(happiness ~ s(age) + s(edu) + s(mobility), family = octa(R=5), data = data) plot(fit, xlab = c("年龄","教育”))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply change the column names, not sure how to do this in Chinese though.

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)[1:3]
names(dat)[2:3] <- c("ONE", "TWO")
b <- gam(y~s(ONE)+s(TWO),data=dat)
plot(b,pages=1,residuals=TRUE)  ## show partial residuals
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never used chinese column names. it work well.

Comment: You're welcome @bigduoduo ! Please make a copy-paste-ready reproducible example next time as I did. You can find help here: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)